# Rails link_to with fa_icon and html properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to use

Rails `link_to` function with `fa_icon` (FontAwesome gem)

like below?

```
=link_to fa_icon("off"), destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete', {"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "data-original-title" => "Logout", "data-placement" => "bottom", :class => "btn btn-metis1 btn-sm"}
```

Comment: wht does it render? I couldnt find the gem `fa_icon`. I guess its just a helper.

Comment: `fa_icon("off")` renders to `<i class="fa fa-off"></i>`. I do not see a reason why that should be a problem or may fail. What problems do you have?

Comment: Whats the output of the wohle link_to line? normally something like this should work. if you get as output this text of the link_to `<i class="fa fa-off"></i>`, you could try `fa_icon("off").html_safe`

Answer (score 8):

link_to (fa_icon "off"), other_options_go_here

That works for me.

Answer (score 6):

This usually works fine.

```
<%= link_to new_message_path, :class=> "you_class" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true" target="_blank"></i>
<% end %>
```

P.S any other html properties can be placed like the id, class etc. And noticed, It's better to place everything in a single line, like:

```
<%= link_to new_message_path, :class=> "you_class" do %><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true" target="_blank"></i><% end %>
```

else it outputs some character to the right, just after the icon.

Answer (score 0):

option pair for data-* attributes should be this way.

```
=link_to fa_icon("off"), destroy_user_session_path, data: { "toggle" => "tooltip", "original-title" => "Logout", "placement" => "bottom" }, :method=>'delete', :class => "btn btn-metis1 btn-sm"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

ran into this problem when setting up our footer.

#### Solution:

```
<%= link_to fa_icon("twitter"), 
            "https://twitter.com/UrTwitterHandle", 
            target: "_blank", 
            class: "social-icon-link twitter-icon", 
            aria: { label: "Twitter" }, 
            title: "Twitter" 
%>
```